# How to keep fork master branch in sync with azerothcore master branch

Tags: azerothcore

How can I automatically keep my fork master branch in sync with the AzerothCore master branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GitHub Actions to keep your fork master branch in sync:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 */6 * * *"
jobs:
  repo-sync:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: repo-sync
      uses: wei/git-sync@v2
      with:
        source_repo: "https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk.git"
        source_branch: "master"
        destination_repo: "https://${{ secrets.GH_USERNAME }}:${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ secrets.GH_USERNAME }}/azerothcore-wotlk.git"
        destination_branch: "master"
```

Create the secrets in the fork repo settings. You can refer here on how to add them:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository

In my case I created the secrets `GH_USERNAME` and `GH_TOKEN`

`GH_USERNAME` should be set to your github username.

`GH_TOKEN` should be set to a personal access token that you create.

Refer here for information on how to create one:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token